# calling onMissingTemplate function if cfinclude template is missing

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

the `Application.cfc's onMissingTemplate` function is a great place to catch error if the user accesses a template in url which does not exists.

But as I have templates which dynamically include the other templates using `cfinclude` tag. But but if this dynamically generated path does not exist coldfusion does not calls the `onMissingTemplate` function.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Use the oneError() function.

Answer (score 1):

you could catch the error with a cfcatch:

```
<cftry>
    <cfset x = 'templateName'>

    <cfinclude template="#x#.cfm">

    <cfcatch type="MissingInclude">
       //Do something
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: You could, but then you have to do it on every page that has an include.